# How to have `v-divider` components between each `v-list-item`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to iterate a v-divider based on how many answers i have, so that i have a divider for each answer (4). Taking a cue from an [example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#card-list) on the official documentation i'm trying something like this but i can't get to the head, someone can explain to me where am i wrong?
[image]

This is the code:

```
<template>
  <div class="dark2">
    <v-card max-width="600" class="mx-auto">
      <v-toolbar extended class="mt-10" color="light-blue" dark>
        <v-toolbar-title class="flex text-center">
          <h2 class="text-center mt-10">Quiz Dark 2</h2>
        </v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>

      <v-progress-linear :value="progress"></v-progress-linear>

      <v-list subheader two-line v-for="(element, index) in questions.slice(a,b)" :key="index" v-show="quiz">
        <h1 class="text-center my-4">Domanda {{ b }}/{{ questions.length }}</h1>
        <v-list-item class="d-flex justify-center text-center">{{ element.question }}</v-list-item>
        <v-divider class="mt-10"></v-divider>

        <v-list-item-group active-class="pink--text">
          <v-list-item class="d-flex justify-center my-2" v-for="(item, index) in element.suggestions" :key="index">
            {{ item.suggestion }}
          </v-list-item>
          <v-divider v-if="index < questions.length - 1"
                     :key="index"></v-divider>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>

    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [
        {
          question: 'Cosa lascia Micheal kanhnwald a suo figlio Jonas prima di impiccarsi?',
          suggestions: [
            {suggestion: 'Un libro'},
            {suggestion: 'Una lettera'},
            {suggestion: 'Una torcia futuristica'},
            {suggestion: 'Un contatore Geiger'}
          ]
        }
      ],
      a: 0,
      b: 1,
      select: false,
      score: 0,
      quiz: true,
      score_show: false,
      next: false,
      progress: 0
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in the examples provided by Vuetify official document [Lists Component / Action stack](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#action-stack), you should be having a `template` tag inside your `v-list-item-group` tag. Something like this:

```
  <v-list-item-group active-class="pink--text">
    <template v-for="(item, index) in element.suggestions">
      <v-list-item class="d-flex justify-center my-2" :key="index">
        {{ item.suggestion }}
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider
          v-if="index < element.suggestions.length - 1"
          :key="`${index}-divider`"
      ></v-divider>
    </template>
  </v-list-item-group>
```

The only difference is having `template` inside `v-list-item-group` and then adding `v-divider` next to `v-list-item` inside the custom `template`.

Hope it helps, happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, i took your advice. This however does not help me to fix the problem with the v-divider, it does not create one for each element in the "suggestions" list

Comment: Sorry, I missed correcting the `v-if` section mathematics, I edited the answer, try the new one with `index < (element.suggestions.length - 1)`

Comment: nothing, the v-divider is placed next to the element, but it should go below it
https://i.gyazo.com/917aafdc

Comment: The link doesn't exist, and btw I updated the codes, did you replace `v-divider` with `<v-divider v-if="index < (element.suggestions.length - 1)" :key="index"></v-divider>` ?
The `if` condition was wrong before

Comment: Yes i did but this is what happens, while the v-divider should be under each item
https://i.gyazo.com/1d7bcdfe5b6263535ed10936f6311aa0.png

Comment: @DanieleCadicina you were right, I've placed the sub `template` tag in the wrong place, try the newly edited code, this must be the final solution for your problem

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying.. This is actually how it works, but i get errors in the console due to the v-divider (if i delete that part of the code no error is detected) what is it due to? Forgive the question
https://i.gyazo.com/3ccca78c3adc272a4b6de67cb197ee8c.png

Comment: At the moment i have stemmed the problem in this way:
<v-divider v-if = "index <element.suggestions.length - 1": key = "index.suggestions"> </v-divider>
is it a viable solution?

Comment: @DanieleCadicina Did you update your codes with the latest updated code I wrote above?
Post me the result of the above code

Comment: Yes, i updated the code that way, and the last picture taken where the error is in the console uses that code.. Actually i have stemmed the problem by changing the: key =: "index" in: key =: "index.suggestions" and everything works, but i don't know if it is correct

Comment: Sorry I missed one of the comments, that was due to the same indexing for both divider and item, I've changed divider index to:
 :key="`${index}-divider`"
, change it to this and you're good to go
Be sure to place backticks like the updated code

Comment: Perfect, everything works, thank you very much for your time and your help!

Answer (score 0):

A little better variant is to show divider if index != 0 `v-show="index !== 0"`

```
<v-list-item-group active-class="pink--text">
 <template v-for="(item, index) in element.suggestions">
  <v-divider v-show="index !== 0"></v-divider>
  <v-list-item class="d-flex justify-center my-2" :key="index">
    {{ item.suggestion }}
  </v-list-item>
 </template>
</v-list-item-group>
```